# How can I add text to a textbox before a certain occurrence of a character?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Right now, I have a text box adding text indicators around added text. For instance, when someone writes, "He is a dad" it comes out as "NOTE (SALE): He is a dad (8/27/2024)(5:44:00pm)(3608)" using this code:

```
If Not Mark1.NEWCALLHISTORYTEXTBOX.Value = "" And Not InStr(Mark1.NEWCALLHISTORYTEXTBOX.Value, "NOTE ") > 0 Then Mark1.NEWCALLHISTORYTEXTBOX.Value = "NOTE (" & Mark1.NEWDISPODROPDOWN.Value & "): " & Mark1.NEWCALLHISTORYTEXTBOX.Value & " (" & Date & ")" & "(" & Time & ")" & "(" & Mark1.REPNUMBERTEXTBOX.Value & ")."
```

My issue is I want to be able to change certain parts of the textbox when something else on the userform is changed without changing the entire note around it.

For instance, when the value in "Mark1.NEWDISPODROPDOWN.Value" changes, I want it to update just that part in the string without changing anything else.

I don't know to specify just that area and am having trouble figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were right, `SALE` is coming from Mark1.NEWDISPODROPDOWN.Value in your sample. Provided code update 'SALE' to 'NewText'.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim sTxt, sNewTxt, arrText1, arrText2
    sTxt = "NOTE (SALE): He is a dad (8/27/2024)(5:44:00pm)(3608)"
    arrText1 = Split(sTxt, ")")
    arrText2 = Split(arrText1(0), "(")
    arrText2(1) = "NewText" ' Mark1.NEWDISPODROPDOWN.Value
    arrText1(0) = Join(arrText2, "(")
    sNewTxt = Join(arrText1, ")")
    Debug.Print sNewTxt
End Sub
```

If it always has the same pattern `NOTE (xx):..`, the code could be simpler.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim sTxt, sNewTxt, sUpdateText
    sTxt = "NOTE (SALE): He is a dad (8/27/2024)(5:44:00pm)(3608)"
    sUpdateText = "NewText" ' Mark1.NEWDISPODROPDOWN.Value
    sNewTxt = "NOTE (" & sUpdateText & Mid(sTxt, InStr(sTxt, ")"))
    Debug.Print sNewTxt
End Sub
```

**Output**

```
NOTE (NewText): He is a dad (8/27/2024)(5:44:00pm)(3608)
```

Comment: by same pattern, do you mean if it is always "NOTE ("X"):"?

Comment: Yes, it starts with `NOTE `, the replaced text within `()`.

Comment: so would stxt just be the value of the textbox im trying to change?

Comment: Yes, sTxt is the value of the textbox and update the textbox with sNewTxt at the end.

Comment: hmm. i tried to add this to a change sub like this:
`Dim sTxt, sNewTxt, sUpdateText
    sTxt = Mark1.NewCallHistoryTextBox.Value
    sUpdateText = Mark1.NEWDISPODROPDOWN.Value
    sNewTxt = "NOTE (" & sUpdateText & Mid(sTxt, InStr(sTxt, ")"))
    Debug.Print sNewTxt`

Comment: this did not pop up an error code but also did not do anything at all

Comment: nevermind! added `Mark1.NewCallHistoryTextBox.Value = sNewTxt` to the end and it now works. thank you!